# WebStorm: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://evil.com/

Tags: cors, webstorm

I am developing an AngularJs app on localhost. Up until now, I have been using a CORS plug-in for Chrome. Even when I disable it, the following happens.

I haven't been able to [debug both client & server simultaneously](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21624/ide-to-develop-ajax-angularjs-and-php).

Then I got the idea to run both Brackets and WebStorm simultaneously, but I get the following error

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
>   'http://evil.com/The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains
>   multiple values 'http://evil.com/

Since I never heard of `evil.com` before, I image that this is a WebStorm configuration thing, but I just bought WebStorm and I'm new to it.

Btw, I know that WebStorm is debugging on port 63342, I changed `'http://localhost/'` to `'http://localhost:63342/'`, to try to breakpoint in WebStorm, which caused the error. When I remove it, my code works.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: this is not something specific to WebStorm - this message just means that you have specified several domains in 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. What server is your Angular application hosted on? 'http://localhost:63342/' is the URL of WebStorm built-in webserver, but you are not restricted to use this server only, you can run/debug your application on a webserver of your choice

Comment: I am running on localhost. My code does nothing for CORS; it seems that it is added by WebStorm, although Brackets might be doing so too

Comment: I wonder.. "http://evil.com" is only 1 origin. Your messages says there are multiple values. Which are the other values?

Answer (score 0):

evil.com is added when using the chrome extension `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. I'm not sure if your Brackets and WebStorm environment will be able to work by disabling it, but it should resolve the evil.com part anyway.